# Jenkins: Deploying Job to Tomcat server

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, jenkins

I used the following tutorial to Deploy a Jenkins Job to Tomcat server:
http://macgyverdev.blogspot.nl/2014/02/how-to-make-jenkins-install-packaged.html.

The build finishes succesvol except it doesn't actually deploy the job to tomcat.

I don't understand what has to be filled in the textboxes "War/Ear file" and "Context Path"

This is what i have now:
[image: http://puu.sh/bkRM3/8fff01066c.png]

Console output after build says "Finished: Succes" but doesn't actually include the following lines:

```
Deploying /home/johan/.jenkins/jobs/UnitConversion/workspace/target/Unitconversion.war to container Tomcat 7.x Remote
  Redeploying [/home/johan/.jenkins/jobs/UnitConversion/workspace/target/Unitconversion.war]
  Undeploying [/home/johan/.jenkins/jobs/UnitConversion/workspace/target/Unitconversion.war]
  Deploying [/home/johan/.jenkins/jobs/UnitConversion/workspace/target/Unitconversion.war]
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: do you have access to see the Jenkins log? is the Test.war built correctly and present in the target folder?

Comment: Hallo, I don't understand what you mean with Jenkins log. Do you mean the Console Output after build? I can comfirm that the Test.war is built correctly and present in the target folder. If i place it manually in the tomcat webapps folder, it's works withouth a problem.